# Can I change the text "[CíviMail Draft]" in a language that local users underdtands?

Tags: civimail

My fellow boardmembers of our marineclub are less familiair with bulk-mailings  and concepts. They reply on the draft mail, as if it was the right mail. I think if I change the text  "[CíviMail Draft]" into some text in local language, I will have a better response. Where and how can I change this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CiviCRM has a feature called 'Word Replacement' which you can find under Admin > Customise, or at civicrm/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1 which I think is worth trying out.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. It works exactly as I wanted!!  It took a while for me before I was able to check it, because it works only when a new bulk mail is made. Not for an existing one.

Comment: Good to hear Dee. Could you complete the Stack Exchange process then by ticking the above answer so SE knows it has been 'accepted'